# Boolean assignment vs declaration

Tags: java, boolean, variable-assignment

I don't understand why when I instantiate booleans I can do:

```
boolean a, b, c = false;
```

and have them all be assigned to false, but later on when I want to modify the values I can't do

```
a, b, c = true;
```

Does someone know why this is?

Comment: Because that's the syntax of the language.

Comment: `a, b, c = false` is not `a = b = c = false`; it`s "set c to false and a and b to whatever the default is (which is also false)"

Comment: Use `boolean a = false, b = false, c = false;`

Comment: @tobias_k does assignment then start from right to left?

Comment: `boolean a = false, b, c;` What do you think happens here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
boolean a, b, c = false;
```

You *declare* `a`, `b` and `c` here, but only *assign* `c`. As in:

```
boolean a;
boolean b;
boolean c = false;
```

If you want to assign each of the variables, you have to make it explicit:

```
boolean a = false, b = false, c = false;
```

(But at that point it would probably be more readable to split it into multiple lines.)

Consequently, it makes no sense to have

```
a, b, c = true;  // invalid
```

You can, however, use

```
a = b = c = true;  // valid
```

to assign `a`, `b` and `c` all to `true`.

Comment: So the second one is really like:

`a; b; c = true;`

Which is nonsensical?

Comment: @jhobbie I suppose you could say that. It just comes down to the fact that it's syntactically invalid to use commas in an expression like that.